# Inputing the checkbox groups in a way to exclude the selected boxes

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Hi i am doing a Rshiny dashboard with a group of three variables that I want to represent as choices to be selected or not.If the user do not tick the box, it should be excluded from the data file, feed into a clustering model.

I have trouble to connecting it to my input data, in a way that the un-selected variable gets excluded from the data put in the model:

here's the sample code- any help is appreciated.

```
  titlePanel("Customer"),

    sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(
                    sliderInput("Clusters",
                                "Number of Clusters:",
                                min = 1,
                                max = 10,
                                value = 1
                  ),

                                    checkboxGroupInput("Checkboxgroup", 
                                       h3("variable selection"), 
                                       choices = list("v1" = 1, 
                                                      "v2" = 2, 
                                                      "v3" = 3),
                                       selected = c(1, 2, 3))

    ),                  mainPanel(position="right",
                            plotOutput("distPlot", height = 500, width = 500)
                  )
    )

)

server <- function(input, output) {

data_train= data[ ,3:14]
### here is where i need to excluded the selected boxes from the data_train on the above line

 k_means=reactive({
    kmeans(data_train, centers=input$Clusters, nstart = 50)
  })


  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

    plotcluster(data_train, k_means()$cluster)   

  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to me that you never used your checkboxgroup inside your server. Plus, the variables that you can exclude are not as options in checkboxgroup, but v3. I'm gonna suggest something assuming that you only want variables 3, 4 and 5 as likely to be excluded. Plus, I'm also assuming that you only want variables 3 to 14, as it's that what you do.

First, you change your checkbox as follows:

```
checkboxGroupInput("Checkboxgroup", 
                                       h3("variable selection"), 
                                       choices = list("v3" = 3, 
                                                      "v4" = 4, 
                                                      "v5" = 5),
                                       selected = c(3:5))
```

then you can change the line where you define your training set as follows:

```
mytrain=reactive({
vars=3:14;vars=vars[!vars%in%as.numeric(input$Checkboxgroup)]
data_train= data[ ,vars]
data_train
})
```

and your analysis:

```
k_means=reactive({
    kmeans(mytrain(), centers=input$Clusters, nstart = 50)
  })
```

If I correctly understood your problem, that should do it.

Comment: Thanks so much I think it clears up lots of things for me- I'll try this solution- is that the variables we declare as  "v3" = 3 etc,  3 indicates the column number of the data file on the server? in my example variable "V1" was column 3 of my data.